# AND clause on multiple values for same column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I fix this query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_notifications
WHERE notification_status = '0'
  AND notification_sent_to = ?
  AND notification_category = 'ticket reply'
  AND notification_category = 'groupdoc'
```

I need to count result filtering only notification category for ticket reply and groupdoc.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If `notification_status` is an integer, you should remove the single quotes

Comment: Hi,yes it is an int, many thanks for your help, it works in both ways but i'll follow your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particular column can have only one value in a given row. So the following condition can never be True

```
notification_category = 'ticket reply'AND notification_category= 'groupdoc'
```

When people think I need rows with value of 'a' `and` rows with value of 'b', the actual logical operator to use is OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_notifications WHERE notification_status = '0' AND notification_sent_to=? AND
 (notification_category = 'ticket reply' OR notification_category= 'groupdoc')
```

Comment: yes well spotted. I've corrected before the comment but I see that you have an answer with the brackets already. +1 from me

Comment: Many thanks, i've tried also SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_notifications WHERE notification_status = '0' AND notification_sent_to=? AND (notification_category LIKE 'ticket reply' OR notification_category LIKE 'groupdoc') and seem to work but i prefer your solution ;)

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project

Comment: the LIKE clause is for when you want to do inexact matching. Eg LIKE 'ticket%' this will match anything that begins with ticket. It will be a lot slower too

Comment: Hi, many thanks i've learned something new today thanks to you ;)

Answer (score 2):

A column can not have 2 values at same time. I think what you want is an `OR`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM user_notifications 
WHERE notification_status = 0 AND notification_sent_to=? 
   AND (notification_category = 'ticket reply' OR notification_category= 'groupdoc')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_notifications
WHERE notification_status = 0 AND
      notification_sent_to = ? AND
      notification_category IN ('ticket reply', 'groupdoc');
```